Android 14 crashing with libc of OpenCV
I'm doing a project in which I use OpenCV to manipulate some images, and everything is ok on android 13 or previous, but I've updated my S23 to Android 14 (OneUI 6.1) and now android studio crash with the next error, its strange because I don't touch anything about OpenCV when the crash arrive. And arrives everytime, but randomly.
Any advice?
2024-04-09 20:30:02.804 14278-14278 libc                    com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug      A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1cbb7ef8b97324 in tid 14278 (.cerambyx.debug), pid 14278 (.cerambyx.debug)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.278 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A  Cmdline: com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug
2024-04-09 20:30:03.278 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A  pid: 14278, tid: 14278, name: .cerambyx.debug  >>> com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug <<<
2024-04-09 20:30:03.278 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #00 pc 0000000000889550  /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk (offset 0x1bcc000)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.278 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #01 pc 000000000088a964  /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk (offset 0x1bcc000)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.278 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #02 pc 00000000005e9600  /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk (offset 0x1bcc000)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.278 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #37 pc 000000000035eab8  [anon:dalvik-classes21.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes21.dex] (com.google.mediapipe.tasks.vision.core.BaseVisionTaskApi.<clinit>+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #48 pc 00000000000016bc  [anon:dalvik-classes20.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes20.dex] (com.victormartin.cerambyx.opencv.InteractiveSegmentationHelper.setupInteractiveSegmenter+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #53 pc 0000000000001538  [anon:dalvik-classes20.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes20.dex] (com.victormartin.cerambyx.opencv.InteractiveSegmentationHelper.<init>+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #58 pc 0000000000002910  /data/data/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes11.dex (com.victormartin.cerambyx.ui.photointeractivesegmentation.PhotoInteractiveSegmentationFragment$setActions$1$1.invokeSuspend+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #63 pc 00000000000028e4  /data/data/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes11.dex (com.victormartin.cerambyx.ui.photointeractivesegmentation.PhotoInteractiveSegmentationFragment$setActions$1$1.invoke+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #68 pc 00000000000028c0  /data/data/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes11.dex (com.victormartin.cerambyx.ui.photointeractivesegmentation.PhotoInteractiveSegmentationFragment$setActions$1$1.invoke+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #73 pc 00000000002d4f80  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.lifecycle.RepeatOnLifecycleKt$repeatOnLifecycle$3$1$1$1$1$1$1.invokeSuspend+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #78 pc 00000000002d4f54  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.lifecycle.RepeatOnLifecycleKt$repeatOnLifecycle$3$1$1$1$1$1$1.invoke+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #83 pc 00000000002d4f30  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.lifecycle.RepeatOnLifecycleKt$repeatOnLifecycle$3$1$1$1$1$1$1.invoke+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #88 pc 00000000001dbf88  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #93 pc 000000000019b8e0  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #98 pc 00000000002d5094  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.lifecycle.RepeatOnLifecycleKt$repeatOnLifecycle$3$1$1$1$1.invokeSuspend+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #103 pc 0000000000154578  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #108 pc 000000000019d3e4  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #113 pc 000000000019ebd4  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #118 pc 00000000001d5594  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #123 pc 00000000001dbf30  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #128 pc 00000000001dbe5c  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #134 pc 000000000019bd78  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #139 pc 000000000019720c  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #144 pc 00000000001980ac  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #149 pc 00000000001981c0  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #154 pc 0000000000198074  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #160 pc 00000000001981a4  [anon:dalvik-classes22.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk!classes22.dex] (kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.279 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #166 pc 00000000000038a8  /data/data/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes11.dex (com.victormartin.cerambyx.ui.photointeractivesegmentation.PhotoInteractiveSegmentationFragment.setActions+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.280 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #171 pc 000000000000375c  /data/data/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes11.dex (com.victormartin.cerambyx.ui.photointeractivesegmentation.PhotoInteractiveSegmentationFragment.onViewCreated+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.280 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #176 pc 00000000002c8e64  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.280 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #181 pc 00000000002c0920  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.280 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #186 pc 00000000002c120c  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.280 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #191 pc 00000000002be2e8  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.280 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #196 pc 00000000002bee3c  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.280 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #201 pc 00000000002bc01c  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions+0)
2024-04-09 20:30:03.280 14515-14515 DEBUG                   pid-14515                            A        #206 pc 00000000002b9d1c  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~1jnN6Va-vnscxUguu2mgAQ==/com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug-ncHCEB8xlqIL1DSbRDLtpw==/base.apk] (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run+0)
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (14278) for package com.victormartin.cerambyx.debug ----------------------------


[mre] required. traceback doesn't show usage of OpenCV, only your own namespace happening to incorporate the string "opencv"
